# Не удаётся подключиться к веб-серверу "IIS Express"

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

Из неоткуда появилась проблема. Получаю ошибку при попытке запустить проект из под IIS Express. Испробовал все танцы с бубном, что нашел в сети. Кто сталкивался, дайте совет пожалуйста, что делать? Готовлюсь к переустановке винды.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075358/visual-studio-2017-unable-to-connect-to-web-server-iis-express

В папке проекта необходимо удалить папку ".vs" и открыть проект заново.

П.С. Папка скрытая. В параметрах проводника выставите "Показывать скрытые файлы, папки и диски"